# Swift mangled function name mapping

Tags: swift, x86, disassembly, hopper

How does the Hopper disassembler understand what is the function's name?

For example, I have a simple Swift function named function(), and after disassembling the executable with that function Hopper shows me that it's mangled name is __T04file8functionyy. I can find the location of these symbols in the executable file, but I can't find how does it map the address of the function with it's name.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/Mangling.rst) helps.

Comment: did you try Hopper v4?  It automatically de-mangles Swift code. So you can see the mangled and de-mangled name together in Hopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this Mach-O file format reference:
https://github.com/aidansteele/osx-abi-macho-file-format-reference

So the answer to my question is that there is a special struct called **nlist_64**, which contains the address of the function in the executable and the index of the mangled name of that function in the symbol table.

Answer (score 11):

You can read the name mangling specs [straight from Apple](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/Mangling.rst).

If you only want a quick way to demangle the name, type the following in Terminal:

```
swift demangle __T04file8functionyy
```

Output:

```
_T04file8functionyy ---> filefunction empty-list  empty-list
```

(I'm not sure if the mangled name you provided is valid)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking how does name mangling work, that's pretty straightforward. I'm interested in where exactly in the executable we can find that a function at a specific address has a specific name, which is stored in the same file.